# Find all local extrema for $f(x,y)=8y^3+12x^2-24xy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Since $f$ is everywhere differentiable, critical points $(x,y)$ are such that

$$\nabla f(x,y)=24(x-y,y-x)=(0,0) \iff x=y$$

For these points the Hessian vanishes, so we can't use the Second Derivative Test. But we know that if $(x,y)$ is a local extremum, then $x=y$. Let's study then the composition $(f \circ c)(t): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $c:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2, c(t)=(t,t)$.

$$(f \circ c)'(t)=24t(t-1)=0 \iff t=1 \lor t=0$$

**Does this mean that $(0,0), (1,1)$ are the only critical points we need consider?** Why? And how do we prove whether they are relative extrema?

Comment: If there is a local extremum, $f$ will attain it on the line $x = y$. Therefore, you are looking for local extrema of the one-dimensional function $\tilde{f}(x) = 8x^3 + 12 x^2 - 24x^2 = 8x^3 - 12x^2$ as you wrote. The stationary points of $\tilde{f}$ are in $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, and for checking whether this are indeed local extrema, you can use the second derivative of $\tilde{f}$.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't $\nabla f = 24(x-y,y^2-x)$? Setting this equal to $(0,0)$, we have $x=y=y^2$ and only $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are critical points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote down the gradient incorrectly. Only $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are, in fact, critical points.

To answer your question, though, you should have figured something was wrong. If $\nabla f(P)=0$ for some point $P$, then $P$ will be a critical point for the restriction of $f$ to any curve passing through $P$.